# I get an CertPathValidatorException issue in webview

Tags: android, ssl, webview, ssl-certificate, self-signed

This is my webview:

```
  if(bundle != null){
        String file = bundle.getString("url");
        Log.i("","url is:" + file);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        wv.loadUrl(file);
    }
```

This is my WebViewClient:

```
  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        wv.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        Log.e("","error is certificate:" + error.getCertificate());
        Log.e("","error is:" + error.getPrimaryError());
        Log.e("","error is url:" + error.getUrl());
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
```

I get this error back:

```
10-12 13:27:43.174: I/X509Util(14748): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Also, the "onReceivedSSLError method is not being reached. I do not get the logs that I added inside that function". What am I doing wrong?

Also this are the permissions that I have, I don't know if I need more or not:

```
android.permission.INTERNET"
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

I even tried to add the certificate to the webview, like this:

```
 try {
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            Certificate cer = keyStore.getCertificate("ca");
            if(cer != null) {
                Log.i("", "certificate is:" + cer);
                Log.i("", "certificate is:" + cer.toString());
                Log.i("", "certificate is:" + cer.getType());
                Log.i("", "certificate is:" + cer.getPublicKey());
                X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) cer;
                SslCertificate sslCert = new SslCertificate(x509);
                wv.setCertificate(sslCert);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("","error trying to get it:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `MyWebViewClient()` contains the SSL error handler. You set it correctly in line 4 of your code snippet:

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

However in line 12 you call again `wv.setWebViewClient(...)` which replaces the previously set WebViewClient. Hence the code is never called...

Comment: Thanks, missed that. will clean it and check again

Comment: I still get that: "10-12 17:21:40.168: I/X509Util(14061): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found." Error. It enters that code and I get my logs. and handler.proceed is called. but it doesn't load anything.
I tried vw.setCertificate(error.getCertificate()) inside onReceivedSSLError, but I get the same thing. And if I do wv.getCertificate it says it's null (it doesn't save it). How can I add the certificate to the Webview?

Comment: try to remove the super call in your `onReceivedSslError`. It executes `handler.cancel()`.

Comment: Removing the onReceivedSslErro did the trick here as well! Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work anymore... I thought it did but after a few hours Google rejected my app:

Comment: google rejected my app:

We rejected RYT Project, with package name br.com.androidtools, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

Vulnerability SSL Error Handler

For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

Comment: Hi @Robert did you see it?

Comment: @RickON: What do you expect? If you call `handler.proceed();` every time it is obvious insecure. If you don't understand how SSL certificate checking works don't overwrite the method `onReceivedSslError`.

Comment: @Robert I have just understood what was really going on. The url target had its SSL "Lets Encrypt" bad configured.